Backing up /boot /system /recovery on a Samsung A520F
I have purchased a used Samsung A520F on which I want to install a custom ROM. Before I start the installation, I would like to back up the /boot, /system and /recoverypartitions so that I can later reset the smartphone to its initial state, if I want to, e.g. in case I want to resell it.
I have already experimented with another smartphone of the same model.
On this phone I have installed twrp on the recovery partition using heimdall.
Using twrp I could back up all other partitions and then install LineageOS.
Using this method I lost the original recovery partition so I cannot reset the device
back to its original state. So, this time around I would like to back up the recovery
partition before installing twrp.
I have found this similar question but, as far as I understand, the answers to that question will not work for me because:

either I have to root my phone first, i.e. modify the boot and/or system partitions before I take a backup,
or I would have to use fastboot to boot into twrp without installing it, which is not supported by Samsung's download mode.

So, I am looking for an alternative solution e.g.

booting an alternative recovery image from the download mode without installing it, or
downloading the partitions I want to backup via USB, or
copying the partitions I want to backup to an SD card (I could not find such an option in the stock recovery, but maybe I have missed something?)

Do you have any hints?
